# How does the channel relate to the energy of a peak in gamma spec?

Tags: spectroscopy, gamma-rays

In Gamma Ray Spectroscopy, what does the channel numbers for several peaks tell us about the energy of each peak? I'm not sure I quite understand the concept of the channel number. I'm sorry I cannot provide much more detail, I'm just struggling with interpreting gamma spec. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

In gamma spectroscopy, an electrical signal is generated in a detector and then shaped and amplified by a pre-amp and linear amplifier. This signal is (hopefully, linearly) proportional to the energy deposited in the detector. This signal is then digitized by more electronics (analog-to-digital converter, ADC), and a memory location in a computer (the 'channel' ) is increased by 1 to indicate the detection of that energy.

A display of the channels shows a histogram of the energies (# of events at each energy). To calibrate the channel vs energy, the experimentalists use a gamma source which has known energies (Eu-152, Co-60, Na-22, 133-Ba, 137-Cs) and matches the histogram centroids (channels of known energy peaks) with the known energies using least-squares fit to either a straight line or a quadratic. For good quality electronics, these are enough,:
$$E=A+B*\mathrm{channel}$$
$$E=A+B*\mathrm{channel}+C*\mathrm{channel}^2$$
$A$, $B$, and $C$ are parameters determined by the fit.
although a cubic fit might be needed in rare cases.of